# Xamarin Forms Android application works first time with login page. Second time page navigation crashes with System.NullReferenceException with

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have developed a xamarin mobile application and it was working fine with the old version of xamarin forms(2.x.x) versions. I updated xamarin forms to 4.1.0.673156 version. Now very first time application works fine. If i run the same application second time i am getting System.NullReferenceException during Page Navigation(await App.Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage(), true);) from MasterDetailPage to Content Page.

In iOS it's working fine.

What i am missing here?

I have updated my packages to the newer versions.

Exception I received is 
08-16 19:36:40.025 D/Mono    (13374): Searching for 'sqlite3_bind_int'.
08-16 19:36:40.043 D/AbsListView(13374): viewType is heaer or footer
08-16 19:36:40.044 D/AbsListView(13374): viewType is heaer or footer
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Thread finished:  #7
The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
08-16 19:36:54.309 D/Mono    (13374): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
08-16 19:36:54.314 D/Mono    (13374): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
08-16 19:36:54.314 D/Mono    (13374): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
08-16 19:36:54.314 D/Mono    (13374): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
08-16 19:36:54.314 D/Mono    (13374): Probing '__android_log_print'.
08-16 19:36:54.314 D/Mono    (13374): Found as '__android_log_print'.
08-16 19:36:54.327 I/MonoDroid(13374): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.UpdateToolbar () [0x000c9] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:973 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.SwitchContentAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated, System.Boolean removed, System.Boolean popToRoot) [0x0017b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:844 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page view, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:602 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.PushViewAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:161 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPushed (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:607 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__87.MoveNext () [0x00059] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:421 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374):   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__57.MoveNext () [0x0014e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:242 
08-16 19:36:54.380 I/MonoDroid(13374): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code to catch this exception as below :

```
public async Task ShowPage()
{
    try
    {
         await App.Navigation.PushAsync(page, true);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
     throw;
    }
}
```

In App.xaml.cs Initializing as below :

```
public static INavigation Navigation = null;
public App()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            var mainPage = new Home();
            Navigation = mainPage.Navigation;
            Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
}
```

Expected is smooth navigation between the content pages.

The Output is "UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Where is your "page" object defined?

Comment: In the same method as await App.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(), true);

Comment: @Nithy After checking updaed code, which page is the second time will navigate to.Then you can check what happens when navigating into it.